# How to await a coroutine until a condition is met?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm new to asynchronous programming in Python and I'm trying to program an example coroutine that awaits until an arbitrary condition is met. Is this a proper way to implement it?

```
async def foo():
    print('foo')   # this is executed before we start checking the condition
    while not condition:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('bar')   # this is executed after the condition is met
```

Comment: The right way to do this is using [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event)s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @L3viathan mentioned, [asyncio.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) can be used to achive it.

Here's little example:

```
import asyncio


async def foo(event):
    while True:
        print('foo')
        await event.wait()
        print('bar')


async def main():
    event = asyncio.Event()

    asyncio.create_task(foo(event))

    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(i)
        event.set()
        event.clear()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: What about when you have no control over the launch of the function you want to wait for?

Comment: @JohnGlen you mean the condition is still in the function and can occur repeatedly? Not sure much can be done then: you need a way to indicate something has happened to be able to react on it one way or another.